# XMLHttpRequest и метод TRACE

Tags: xmlhttprequest, javascript

Доброго времени суток, форумчане.

Возникла такая проблема: проверяю свой сайт на уязвимости, спайдер обнаружил TRACE-уязвимость. Пытаюсь проверить её работу, написал скрипт.

```
<script>
function sendTrace ()
{
    //var xmlHttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    var xmlHttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xmlHttp.open("TRACE", "MY_IP", false);
    xmlHttp.send();
    xmlDoc=xmlHttp.responseText;
    alert(xmlDoc);
}
</script>
<input type=button onClick="sendTrace();" value="Send Trace Request">
```

Только вот консолька ошибку выдаёт:

`Uncaught SecurityError: Failed to execute 'open' on 'XMLHttpRequest': 'TRACE' HTTP method is unsupported.`

Как жить-то дальше? Что не так делаю?

Заранее благодарю всех за помощь. :)

Comment: Всё так, просто данный метод не поддерживается.

Comment: @RubaXa, не поддерживается сервером или `XMLHttpRequest`?

Comment: Если быть точным:

> SECURITY_ERR (18) Вызывается при попытке совершить запрос, запрещённый настройками безопасности в браузере пользователя.

Comment: @RubaXa, читал, что `XMLHttpRequest` может выдать эту ошибку, но, видимо, не полностью понял эту запись. То есть это проблема моего браузера? Как отключить эту защиту, чтоб скрипт сработал?

Comment: Честно, не знаю, может, проще воспользоваться curl?

Comment: @RubaXa, curl поддерживает TRACE? А можно подробнее?

Comment: `curl -v -X TRACE http://www.google.com` и `curl --insecure -v -X TRACE https://www.google.com/`

Comment: @RubaXa, это php или нет? Я, если честно, потерялся. В php мне известен curl, но его синтаксис совсем не такой, как вы написали. Ну или я овощ...